# Push notification not works in firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I have created one new app for push notification in https://console.firebase.google.com. I have followed all steps mentioned at last it shows -unknown app- under the head **Targeting user segment**. [image]

How to test push notification in firebase?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Comment: can you share your android manifest? did you implemented the code in your app to be able to receive notifications ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén I have updated the android manifest file in question. I have implemented only the changes in gradle file `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'`   and included the `google-services.json` file in repo. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

First, for using firebase push notifications add the dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'                   // this line must be included to use FCM
}
```

Add a service that extends `FirebaseMessagingService`

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
 private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
```

In your `Manifest` add this

```
 <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Add a service that extends `FirebaseInstanceIdService`

```
public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

Add it into the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, this makes sure that the service is loaded

```
 <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

You are done implementing firebase push notifications !

Test and send your first push notification from firebase console !

hope it helped

For more info check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl

happy coding !

Comment: Thanks Gaston. I have done the implementation and using my InstanceID I have send push notification from firebase console. But I didn't receive any notifications. I checked the logs. Moreover, in firebase console, the status of my notification is completed but sent count is 0. Please assist.

Comment: are you using an emulator or a device ?

Comment: using emulator. android studio 3

Comment: try it in a phone